# Connect ECS task with Service Discovery

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, service-discovery

here my situation: I have a docker-compose with some container configured in the same networks.
I need that all the containers can communicate with all others, and some of these container had an environment where i need to set the endpoint of another one, like this example:

```
containerA:
  image: imageA:0.0.1
  port:
    - "8080"
  network:
    - net1

containerB:
  image: imageB:0.0.1
  environments:
    - BRIDGE: http://containerA:8080
  network:
    - net1
```

I need now to translate this docker-compose to an ECS Service (one Task for containerA and one Task for containerB).
I'm using ecs-cli without any problem, i can create a Cluster, run services with Fargate, run all the task inside the same VPC, using the same Security Group, and i enabled Service Discovery for all the ECS Services, using the same namespace for all (so i have containerA.namespace1 and containerB.namescape1).
But i have a problem in the connection between this two tasks:
i try so set:

```
BRIDGE: http://containerA:8080
BRIDGE: http://containerA.namespace1:8080
BRIDGE: http://containerA.namespace1.local
BRIDGE: http://containerA.namespace1.local:8080
```

but all this options doesn't work.
I try a "temp" solution for this problem using the public ip generated from taskA, but if i update the task A, the public IP rightly changes and i need redeploy also taskB.
So, the question is: how i can use "hostname" so i can connect to the name of the service and not to the public ip of the task?
thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Having a similar problem here. Did you ever figure this out?

https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#service-names

Refering to this documentation it seems right to use the .local namespace.

Answer (score -1):

[Update based on the thread] The answer originally provided below assumes you are open to evaluate an alternative tool to deploy your compose file on ECS.

It is very likely that if you use the native docker compose integration with ECS you can `up` your compose file and achieve what you want without you doing nothing special.

You can read more about how to do that [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/). BTW the service discovery mechanism you are using is identical to the discovery mechanism I need in the application I have used in the blog. I am fairly confident that it will work for you.

Comment: I dont think this is 1:1 there is a special section on service names, requiring an ending of `.local`

https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#service-names

Wish this were more clear!

Comment: Are you saying that appending `<compose_project_name>.local` works but calling just the service name won't work? All services in the same deployment will use the same `<compose_project_name>` (and `local` of course) so you can call them directly with the service name without having to append `<compose_project_name>.local`.

Comment: not on ECS. 

To scope the instance addrress you need to follow the docs guidance and use `.local`

Comment: From the link you posted: `Services can retrieve their dependencies using Compose service names (as they do when deploying locally with docker-compose), or optionally use the fully qualified names.` The way the compose/ecs integration works is that docker injects the domain name (<namespace>.local) into `/etc/resolv.conf` so that if you only use the service name it will resolve it (by appending <namespace>.local).

Comment: Note I am talking about (and I was suggesting using) [this docker/ecs integration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/) instead of `ecs-cli`. My comments are related to the docker/ecs integration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but this is a question about ECS

Comment: The docker compose integration I was alluding to is indeed about ECS. It's just a different mechanism to deploy to ECS. I would warn about sticking to using ecs-cli because the new CLI experience for ECS is being developed with AWS Copilot right now (which doesn't support the compose format and the docker / compose integration is what we have been suggesting to use instead).

Comment: I have edited my answer to make this more clear.